# Combining a class selector and an attribute selector with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Is it possible to combine both a class selector *and* an attribute selector with jQuery?

For example, given the following HTML:

```html
<TABLE>
  <TR class="myclass" reference="12345"><TD>Row 1</TD></TR>
  <TR class="otherclass" reference="12345"><TD>Row 2</TD></TR>
  <TR class="myclass" reference="12345"><TD>Row 3</TD></TR>
  <TR class="myclass" reference="54321"><TD>Row 4</TD></TR>
</TABLE>
```

What would be the selector I can use to select rows 1 and 3 only?

I have tried:

```js
$(".myclass [reference=12345]") // returns nothing

$(".myclass, [reference=12345]") // returns all 4 rows (yes, I know the comma means 'or')
```

I'm sure the answer is very simple and I have tried searching the jQuery forums and documentation but I can't seem to figure this one out. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 356, accepted):

Combine them. Literally *combine* them; *attach* them together without any punctuation.

```
$('.myclass[reference="12345"]')
```

Your first selector looks for elements with the attribute value, contained in elements with the class.
The space is being interpreted as the [descendant selector](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector).

Your second selector, like you said, looks for elements with either the attribute value, or the class, or both.
The comma is being interpreted as the [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector) operator — whatever that means (CSS selectors don't have a notion of "operators"; the comma is probably more accurately known as a delimiter).

Comment: can i combine id also? i mean like this : $('.myclass[myid="6"]')

Answer (score 19):

I think you just need  to remove the space. i.e.

```
$(".myclass[reference=12345]").css('border', '#000 solid 1px');
```

There is a fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/xXEHY/

Answer (score 8):

This code works too:

```
$("input[reference=12345].myclass").css('border', '#000 solid 1px');
```

Answer (score 2):

This will also work:

```
$(".myclass[reference='12345']").css('border', '#000 solid 1px');
```