# jQuery selector with specific attribute

Tags: jquery, anchor

I've got this code:

```
$('a').click(
   function() {
       $("#change_flash").css("display", "block"); $("#my_flash").css("display", "none");
  });
```

But this one works for all anchor elements. I would like to influence with this script only for anchors elements which contains rel="lightbox" attribute.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: Search of "jQuery selectors class with specific attributes" on Google revealed http://stackoverflow.com/q/6246683/411902

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('a[rel="lightbox"]').click(
   function() {
       $("#change_flash").css("display", "block"); $("#my_flash").css("display", "none");
  });
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the following:

```
$('a[rel="lightbox"]').click(
    function(){
        // do your stuff here
    });
```

This is using the `attribute="value"` notation (see references).

There are, also, other options:

- attribute-begins-with: `attribute^="value"`,
- attribute-ends-with: `attribute$="value",`
- attribute-contains: `attribute*="value".

Note, of course, that while `$('[rel="lightbox"]')` is an absolutely valid selector all by itself, this will cause jQuery to examine *every* element on the page for that attribute and value in order to bind/assign the `click` event(s); therefore it's always best to use a tag-name, hence the `$('a[rel="lightbox"]')`, *or* a class-name in order to limit the number of elements jQuery has to search through to find the matching elements.

Although in modern browsers I seem to remember this 'search' is handed over to the native `document.querySelectorAll()`, rather than using Sizzle, but even so it's best to limit the amount of work a browser need do.

References:

- [attribute-equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector).
- [atrribute-begins-with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-begins-with-selector/).
- [attribute-ends-with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/).
- [attribute-contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/).

Comment: You're absolutely welcome; I'm glad to have been of some help! =)